# How to create a table in email body?

Tags: c#, html, email

I'am using mail message to send email in C# and I want to add a table in the mail body.

I am using a string variable to store html code but its printing the whole string as it is in the mail body.

```
string EPT;
string PRINTER;
string CID;
string htmlString= "<!DOCTYPE html>< html >< body > Hi All, < br /> < br /> Please find below, status of PDS SPOS Devices < br />< br /> < table border='1' >< tr >< th > Device Name </ th >< th > Online Status </ th >< th > Device Status </ th >< th > EPT Status </ th >< th > PRINTER Status </ th >< th > CID Status </ th ></ tr > ";

foreach (RetrieveDeviceData deviceData in SPOSStatusList)
{
    if (deviceData.EPTStatus.Contains("EPT is not returning any error on commands"))
    {
        EPT = "EPT OK";
    }
    else if (!deviceData.EPTStatus.Contains("NA"))
    {
        EPT = "EPT Not OK";
    }
    else
    {
        EPT = "NA";
    }

    if (deviceData.PRINTERStatus.Contains("PRINTER - OK"))
    {
        PRINTER = "PRINTER OK";
    }
    else if (!deviceData.PRINTERStatus.Contains("NA"))
    {
        PRINTER = "PRINTER Not OK";
    }
    else
    {
        PRINTER = "NA";
    }

    if (deviceData.CIDStatus.Contains("CID-OK"))
    {
        CID = "CID OK";
    }
    else if (!deviceData.CIDStatus.Contains("NA"))
    {
        CID = "CID Not OK";
    }
    else
    {
        CID = "NA";
    }

    htmlString = htmlString + "< tr >< td >" + deviceData.DeviceName.ToString() + "</ td >< td >" + deviceData.OnlineStatus.ToString() + "</ td >< td >" + deviceData.DeviceStatus.ToString() + "</ td >< td >" + EPT.ToString() + "</ td >< td >" + PRINTER.ToString() + "</ td >< td >" + CID.ToString() + "</ td ></ tr >";
}


htmlString = htmlString + "</ table >< br /><br /> Regards < br /> Presto CTSS </ body ></ html>";

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailFrom"].ToString());
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailTo"].ToString()));
mailMessage.Subject = "PDS SPOS Device Status Report - " + DateTime.Now;
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.Body = htmlString;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(reportPath + "\\SPOSStatusReport.csv");
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailServerIp"].ToString();
try
{
    client.Send(mailMessage);
    writer.WriteLine("Email sent");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    writer.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

expected result- mail body with a table data
actual- value of htmlString variable in above code is printed as it is in mail.

Comment: this MailMessage class must have property IsBodyHtml. Set it to true.

Comment: Your html string must be broken. Otherwise it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @SteadyReader there is already set IsBodyHtml to true.

Comment: Oh i see, html string is broken. remove spaces please < html > should be <html>. Please for all tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. I removed the spaces in all tags and its working absolutely fine.

Comment: @Thanusha please vote for correct answer. Thanks.